# How to determine if a formula or a manual entry has been written in a cell

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

I have a cell/ entire column that has a formula(s) in it. Sometimes I go into that cell and manually change that value to a different value. The formula goes away and is being over written by the manual entry. How can someone determine later down the line that that cell was being entered automatically with the formula or entered manually? Is there some rule or trick within conditional formatting or elsewhere that can indicate to the viewer that this cell was overwritten or that cell is being formulated by the generic formula.

An example....

if the formula adds a selected range and gives a value and that cell is red now. If I enter a value manually in that cell, that cell now sees that value and turns it 'blue' because it was manually entered. Is there logic in excel that will differentiate this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPD:**

1) add UDF:

```
Function hasFormula(r As Range) As Boolean
    hasFormula = r.hasFormula
End Function
```

2) Select *all cells* and apply following CF rules:

- Blue CF (for values): `=AND(A1<>"",NOT(hasFormula(A1)))`
- Red CF (for formulas): `=hasFormula(A1)`

---

**For Excel 2013** you could use built-in function `ISFORMULA`:

Select *all cells* and apply following CF rules:

- Blue CF (for values): `=AND(A1<>"",NOT(ISFORMULA(A1)))`
- Red CF (for formulas): `=ISFORMULA(A1)`

[image]

**Alternative way** (for higlighting all cells with formulas):

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>, then select *"Special..."->"Formulas"* and press *"OK"*. But it highlights cells only temporary, untill you select any other cell.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried using the blue formula you mentioned however I wasn't able to get the value to change blue. thi is my formula in the cell H6... (=V6-W6*7). This is the CF formula I have in just one cell =AND(H6<>"",ISNA(FORMULATEXT(H6)))  the RED CF I have a different condition. But I am unable to get the blue color when I over write the existing formula in the cell and simply enter a date in it. It just goes to white. I made my default color in the CF blue. Tried sticking a NOT in there but that made everything blue permanently.

Comment: ENGR024, to detect *formulas* use `=NOT(ISNA(FORMULATEXT(H6)))`

Comment: Adding =NOT(ISNA(FORMULATEXT(H6)))   to my CF made the cell blue permanently. I have a formula in the cell now but its blue. When I enter a date it remains blue

Comment: here is my test workbook (when H6 contains *formula* - it's red, when *value* - it's blue, when *empty* - it's white): https://www.dropbox.com/s/v1hnepyz4ta6tlf/test.xlsx

Comment: So when I simply enter today's date, or the value 25; the value still did not turn blue. I am using your link

Comment: how do you enter it: `=25` or `25`?

Comment: I am inputting a number in it without the =. So just 25

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49098/discussion-between-simoco-and-engr024)